# tipo de binding en angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('socialChat')
        .component('messageItem', {
            controller: 'MessageItemController',
            bindings: {
                chatUser: '<',
                instance: '<'
            },
            templateUrl: '/js/social-chat/components/message-item/message-item.html'
        });
})();
```

no entiendo esta parte

```
bindings: {
                    chatUser: '<',
                    instance: '<'
                },
```

que significa esos **operadores <, y creo que existen =,&**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los componentes tienen una API pública para Inputs y Outputs: En AngularJS (Angular 1), al tener two-way binding, cuando se usa '=', los cambios que se hacen al hijo, se reflejan en el padre.

Las entradas (Inputs) tienen que usar < y @, el < denota one-way binding, o sea, relación en un solo sentido. @ se puede usar cuando el input es un string, especialmente cuando el valor no cambia. El = se utiliza para un binding en doble sentido, es decir, cuando cambia el valor en el componente, también cambia en el padre.

```
bindings: {
  hero: '<',
  comment: '@'
}
```

Las Salidas (Outputs) se hacen con &, que funciona como un callback a los eventos del componente:

```
bindings: {
  onDelete: '&',
  onUpdate: '&'
}
```

En vez de manipular la información directamente, se llama al evento en el padre.

```
<editable-field on-update="$ctrl.update('location', value)"></editable-field><br>

<button ng-click="$ctrl.onDelete({hero: $ctrl.hero})">Delete</button>
```

The esta manera el componente padre decide que hacer con el dato.

```
ctrl.deleteHero(hero) {
  $http.delete(...).then(function() {
    var idx = ctrl.list.indexOf(hero);
    if (idx >= 0) {
      ctrl.list.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  });
}
```

En resumen:

< binding de un solo sentido.

@ se utiliza mas que nada para pasar strings. Soporta interpolación {{}}

= binding de doble sentido

& se utiliza para pasar métodos que luego serán utilizados en tu componente.

En caso de que algo no quede claro, no dudes en preguntar nuevamente.

Espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: a que te refieres con padre e hijo_?

Comment: Padre es el componente en el que se inserta/contiene el nuevo componente (hijo)

Comment: como ejecutar una funcion de un controlador desde un servicio?

Comment: No entendí la pregunta